# What does sizeof do?

Tags: c++, sizeof

What is the main function of `sizeof` (I am new to C++). For instance

```
int k=7;
char t='Z';
```

What do `sizeof (k)` or `sizeof (int)` and `sizeof (char)` mean?

Comment: You are missing a ' in your char.

Comment: @Tyler McHenry Timing is little off the mark for me at 0.08 secs.

Comment: @davit: if you're going to learn a programming language you should really try reading a decent introductory book on the language to get the basics, not just leave it to trial, error, guesswork and endless questions on SO.

Comment: It always amuses me when I Google for a question, and the first link is to SO where someone's being berated for asking rather than googling! :)

Comment: The answer on [What does sizeof do?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3203180/919057) should explain what is happening.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question shows no effort at all.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[`sizeof(x)`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/keywords/sizeof) returns the amount of memory (in bytes) that the variable or type `x` occupies. It has nothing to do with the value of the variable.

For example, if you have an array of some arbitrary type `T` then the distance between elements of that array is exactly `sizeof(T)`.

```
int a[10];
assert(&(a[0]) + sizeof(int) == &(a[1]));
```

When used on a variable, it is equivalent to using it on the type of that variable:

```
T x;
assert(sizeof(T) == sizeof(x));
```

As a rule-of-thumb, it is best to use the variable name where possible, just in case the type changes:

```
int x;
std::cout << "x uses " << sizeof(x) << " bytes." << std::endl
// If x is changed to a char, then the statement doesn't need to be changed.
// If we used sizeof(int) instead, we would need to change 2 lines of code
// instead of one.
```

When used on user-defined types, `sizeof` still returns the amount of memory used by instances of that type, but it's worth pointing out that this does not necessary equal the sum of its members.

```
struct Foo { int a; char b; };
```

While `sizeof(int) + sizeof(char)` is typically `5`, on many machines, `sizeof(Foo)` may be `8` because the compiler needs to [pad out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) the structure so that it lies on 4 byte boundaries. This is not always the case, and it's quite possible that on your machine `sizeof(Foo)` will be 5, but you can't depend on it.

Comment: int means that if variable t is given  t=100  than sizeof(t)= 1?

Comment: `sizeof` has nothing to do with the *value* of the variable. It has to do with the type. It is telling you that on your system, all variables of type `int` require 4 bytes of storage.

Comment: It shows 4 because an `int` typically uses up 4 bytes. `sizeof` has nothing to do with the value stored in the variable.

Comment: nit: technically, sizeof does not report the size in bytes, but whatever unit necessary so that sizeof(char) == 1. The is nearly universally bytes, but in theory at least, not necessarily.

Comment: From the standard: "The sizeof operator yields the number of bytes in the object representation of its operand." However, you are right that byte in the standard isn't explicitly defined as 8-bits as it usually is.

Comment: Your first assert is wrong. ` &(a[0])` is an int pointer so pointer arithmetic will make it equal to `a[4]`.

Comment: How efficient is the `sizeof()` operation? If I call `sizeof()` in hundreds of places, is that slow, and should I store it in a variable or something? Something like `int LONG_SIZE = sizeof(long);`?

Answer (score 10):

To add to Peter Alexander's answer: sizeof yields the size of a value or type in multiples of the size of a `char`---`char` being defined as the smallest unit of memory addressable (by C or C++) for a given architecture (and, in C++ at least, at least 8 bits in size according to the standard). This is what's generally meant by "bytes" (smallest addressable unit for a given architecture) but it never hurts to clarify, and there are occasionally questions about the variability of `sizeof (char)`, which is of course always `1`.

Comment: A byte isn't necessarily the "smallest addressable unit for a given architecture".  On some CDC Cyber computers, the smallest addressable unit is a 16-bit word (Address 0 is 16-bits, address 1 is a distinct 16-bits), and they refer to the two halves as bytes.

Comment: @James: Right: my point was that "byte" is an inherently ambiguous term, and no matter how you define it, somebody somewhere will use it differently. Interesting about the CDCs.

Comment: Most people will agree that a byte is 8 bits, and while there used to be some confusion, it's standardized nowadays: IEC 80000-13. In contrast, the smallest addressable unit in a machine is often called a word, and it is machine-dependent. There are 16-, 32-, 64-bit architectures, but even in those contexts, a byte will still be 8 bit.

Answer (score 6):

sizeof() returns the size of the argument passed to it.
[sizeof() cpp reference](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/keywords/sizeof)

Comment: How efficient is the `sizeof()` operation? If I call `sizeof()` in hundreds of places, is that slow, and should I store it in a variable or something? Something like `int LONG_SIZE = sizeof(long);`?

Comment: sizeof() is compile time, so its the best performance you can get, since at runtime thats just a constant number in your code.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` is a compile time unary operator that returns size of data type.
For example:

```
sizeof(int)
```

will return the size of `int` in byte.

Also remember that type sizes are platform dependent.

Check this page for more details: [sizeof in C/C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sizeof-operator-c/)