# Redirecting standard output to integer

Tags: c++, iostream

I was solving the following problem:
*Reverse the digits of an integer.* Now the code for the problem is straightforward.

```
void reverse(int x){
   if(x < 0){
      cout << "-";
      x*=(-1);
   }

   while(x!=0){
      cout << x%10;
      x/=10;
   }
}
```

But the problem asked the answer to be returned as integer. So I was wondering is there any way the output stream can be redirected to an integer. I know I could redirect it to a string and then convert to integer. But is there any direct way?

Comment: Considering integers are rarely thought of or used as a sequence of digits instead of a value, this doesn't really warrant a standard library addition. You could make one akin to `std::ostringstream` if you wanted to.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by *redirect*. Could you elaborate on that, please.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf For instance in the code above, I had to actually return an integer instead of printing it to stdout.

Comment: The "direct" way would be to compute the value that has digits in reverse order, rather than trying to intercept output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `std::ostringstream`, save `std::cout` buffer, and then convert it to int:

```
void reverse(int x)
{
    std::ostringstream local_buffer;
    auto old_buff = std::cout.rdbuf(local_buffer.rdbuf()); // save pointer to std::cout buffer

    if(x < 0){
        std::cout << "-";
        x*=(-1);
    }

    while(x!=0){
        std::cout << x%10;
        x/=10;
    }

    std::cout.rdbuf(old_buff); // back to old buffer

    int rev = std::atoi(local_buffer.str().c_str());

    std::cout << "rev is: " << rev << "\n";
}
```

[Online on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ece28dc3736b2bfd)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `cout` to directly display the result, try storing the result to a variable, say `rev` and return the result.

```
int reverse(int x)
{    
    bool neg = x < 0;
    int rev = 0;

    while (x != 0) {
        rev = (rev * 10) + (x % 10);
        x /= 10;
    }
    return neg ? -rev : rev;
}
```

Comment: This is incomplete at best. Your `rev` variable doesn't have the sign (which is still printed to STDOUT), the function keeps overwriting it so that you only have one digit, and then you do nothing with it. A smart compiler would optimize this function to just `if (x < 0) { cout << "-"; }`. Not what the OP wanted, and not even what *you* wanted, I suppose.

Comment: Does that fix it? This look to me like the simplest, fastest, and overall best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why not creating a function that returns int?

```
#include <cmath> // needed for pow()

int reverse(int x)
{    
  int y=0;
  int numDigits=0;
  int x2=x;

  // first count number of digits

  while(x2!=0){
  x2/=10;
  numDigits++;
  }

  // then do the reversion by adding up in reverse direction

  for(int i=0; i<numDigits; i++){
  y+=(x%10)*pow(10,numDigits-i-1);
  x/=10;
  }

  return y;
}
```

Comment: I know I could do it this way. But I'm not interested in reversing the digit, it's a trivial problem. But that of redirecting output to an integer.

Comment: And if you _did_ just want a reversed integer, there's no need to pre-compute the length; just multiply the answer by 10 as you divide the input by 10: `int ans=0; while(x) { ans = ans * 10 + (x%10); x /= 10; }` (ignoring sign: you'd remember/normalise at the start and apply `ans *= -1` at the end if needed).

Answer (score 1):

You can convert it to a string and go backwards and send it to a stringstream.

```
std::stringstream s;

std::string s = std::to_string(x);
for (std::string::reverse_iterator rit = s.rbegin(); rit != s.rend(); ++rit) {
    std::cout << *rit;
    ss << *rit;
}
std::cout << std::endl;
return stoi(ss.str());
```

Add

```
#include <sstream>
```

I ran the int- and string-version 2.5 mill. times in a loop and the string-version is twice as fast on my macbook pro 2012. 1.2 secs. vs 2.4 secs. Something to consider using strings even though it may be seldom used.

Update:

Another SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372480/reverse-string-c-using-char-array) suggests std::reverse and when I updated the code to

```
auto s = std::to_string(x);
std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
return stoi(s);
```

it used 0.8 secs., three times faster than swapping digits.