# Reversing string using character array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

I wrote a program to reverse string where the string is a character array. The program is :

```
#include<iostream>
void rev(char *str)
{
  char *end;
  end = str;// end will now point to the same address of str
  // now we need to incremet the end pointer upto it encounter null
  if(str)// this checks if the string is present or not
  {
    while(*end)
      ++end;
    --end;// set one character back, since last character is null
    // swap characters from start of string with the end of the string
    // until the pointers meet in middle.
    while(str < end)
    {
      char temp = *str;
      *str++ = *end;
      *end-- = temp;
    }
  }
  std::cout<<"\n The reversed string is : \n";
  std::cout<<str<<std::endl;
}
int main()
{
  char str[500];
  std::cout<<"\n Enter the string : ";
  std::cin.getline(str, sizeof(str));
  rev(str);
  return 0;
}
```

One output instance is :

```
Enter the string : asdfgh

 The reversed string is : 
dsa
```

I want to solve this problem inplace and using character array.

There are many solutions available on internet. I have seen them. But I want to know where I'm going wrong with this implementation. If there is some extra increment in str. I want to know how to correct it.

Comment: This is incredibly confusing for a simple 5 line program.

Comment: Well, you keep incrementing `str` pointer, and at the end of `rev()` it points into the middle of the array...

Comment: Try some separation of concerns. A function named `rev` should reverse. Not dance, not play guitar, not bring you coffee and a croissant, *not print anything*. Reverse.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse String C++ using char array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372480/reverse-string-c-using-char-array)

Comment: _But I want to know where I'm going wrong with this implementation._ You're making it too hard.

Comment: @n.m. Actually you helped me. Printing in main() function is working fine. But generated one more question. That while printing `str` inside the function why it is not printing the whole string.

Comment: We programmers have reduced attention span, that's why we prefer short functions that do one thing. Not so many things to keep track of == good thing. If you insist on doing two things in the same function, you gotta keep track of stuff. For example, when you print `str`, are you sure it's the whole string?  Have you kept track of what you've used `str` for?

Comment: @Ayushibhardwaj The problem is you change the value of `str` in your reversing code and then print it out like it should still point to the beginning of the string, which, of course, it doesn't.

Comment: @Ayushibhardwaj Tell that to your boss. :)

Comment: @Ayushibhardwaj Clearly you're a student. The linked answer is actually almost the same as mine. I think you're in a weird position to be asking people who are trying to help you to delete their answers...

Comment: Why the down-votes? This is a rare question that actually gives a minimum working example and the desired input/output just like the guidelines ask for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the error is that you kept on increasing the `str` pointer and after that decreasing the `end` pointer, which finally met somewhere at the middle of the string. And right after, you printed out the string which starts somewhere from the middle in reverse order. So, I would suggest to do as follows:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
void rev(char *str) {
  char *end;
  end = str;

  if(str) {
    while(*end)
        ++end;
    --end;

    while(str < end) {
      char temp = *str;
      *str++ = *end;
      *end-- = temp;
    }
  }
  /* Don't print the string here itself */
}

int main() {
  char str[500];
  std::cout<<"\n Enter the string : ";
  std::cin.getline(str, sizeof(str));
  rev(str);

  /* Print your string here */
  std::cout<<"\n The reversed string is : \n";
  std::cout<<str<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
 Enter the string : qwertyuiop

 The reversed string is : 
poiuytrewq
```

Comment: @erip No, this code works because, by moving the printing outside the function, it prints out a *copy* of the pointer that is used to reverse the string.

Comment: This appears to be the only correct answer to the actual question being asked.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're making the problem too confusing.

```
void reverse(char* s) {
  // return if s is nullptr
  if(!s) return;

  size_t len = strlen(s);

  // swap ith from front with ith from back
  for(size_t i = 0; i < len/2; ++i) {
    char temp = s[i];
    s[i] = s[len - i - 1];
    s[len - i - 1] = temp;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not a helpful answer. Internet is full of such answers.

Comment: @Ayushibhardwaj You didn't ask the right question. :)

Comment: Nice. I suppose you could have used `std::swap`, though, no?

Comment: @AmiTavory Yeah, definitely could have.

Comment: The OP is not asking to copy someone else's solution, the question is where the OP's code is going wrong.

Comment: @Galik I answered before OP updated the question... Originally the "question" was _I want to solve this problem inplace and using character array._

Comment: @erip Thanks for your help.

Comment: Okay I can see that. But I think it was implied that they were asking why their code was not working. The revision clears that up though.

Answer (score 3):

Well, since this is tagged c++, you should note that you can do this as

```
void rev(char* str)
{
    std::reverse(str, str + strlen(str));
}
```

Looking at the [documentation for `std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) you can deduce that it does it in place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

int main()
{
    char str[500], revstr[500];
    int i,j,len;
    std::cout<<"\n Enter the string : ";
    std::cin.getline(str, sizeof(str));

    //reverse str
    len = strlen(str);
    for(i=len-1, j=0; i>=0; i--, j++){
        revstr[j]=len[i];
    }
    revstr[j] = '\0'; //marks end of string

    std::cout<<"\n The reversed string is : \n";
    std::cout<<revstr<<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry, but i didn't asked for this.

Comment: This solution doesn't fulfill the in-place requirement.