# C++ reversing a string

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to reverse a string in my C++ code line below `revStr.at(j) = str.at(size);`

But it doesn't change any of the elements in `revStr`.

Is there another way to do it without using any libraries.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;


int main() {

    ostringstream d;

    long long c = 123456789;
    d << c;
    //cout << c << endl;
    string str = d.str();
    //cout << str.at(0) << endl;
    int size = str.size() - 1;
    //cout << size << endl;
    ostringstream e;
    e << str;
    string revStr = e.str();

for (int i = size; size==0; size--) {
    //cout << str.at(size);

        int j = 0;
        revStr.at(j) = str.at(size);
        j++;

} // End For

cout << "Original String is  :" << str << endl;
cout << "Reversed String is  :" << revStr << endl;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse String C++ using char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24372480/reverse-string-c-using-char-array)

Comment: Why do you want to do this without any library?   You do realise that `ostringstream`, `string`, and `cout` are all in the standard C++ library, so not using any library would mean you rely on non-standard mechanisms of output.   With the standard library `std::reverse(revStr.begin(), revStr.end())` meets the requirement in one simple line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes made to the piece of code in question, it works.

```
 for (unsigned int i = size; size >= 0; size--) {

            revStr[j] = str[size];
            j++;

        }
```

Answer (score 8):

Use [std::reverse](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse):

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string test{"Hello"};
    std::cout << "Original string: " << test << std::endl;
    std::reverse(test.begin(), test.end());
    std::cout << "Reversed string: " << test << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Original string: Hello
Reversed string: olleH
```

Comment: I don't want to use an embedded function to reverse

Comment: @DanaAmin What do you mean by “embedded function”? What’s the sense in which `std::reverse` would be embedded in `main`, but `std::string::at` isn’t?

Comment: I'm practicing programming man. Its for practice and I want to write a program that reverses a number.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to reverse a string, you should use [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse), as described by Tyler Lewis. It is the best option.

---

If you want to learn C++, then writing your own version is good practice.

The line

```
for (int i = size; size==0; size--)
```

means “Create a new `int` called `i` and set it to `size` initially. Then, while `size` is zero, do the following and then decrement `size`”.

There are three problems with this:

1. Size is not zero unless you entered a one-character string
2. Since you never use `i`, there’s no point in declaring it
3. Inside the loop you use `j` which is set to zero each time.

You can fix the first by changing the middle part of the `for` loop to `size >= 0` (but be careful—if you later change it so that `size` is an `unsigned` type, because it doesn’t make sense for it to be negative, that code won’t work; it’s generally better to increment going up instead). You can fix the second by using `i` everywhere in the loop statement, and not changing `size`. You can fix the third by using `i` in the loop body, and not declaring a new variable inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed you used std::string so I used std function swap and string. Depending on if you consider this as a 'library'. There are several definitions of 'reverse'. You could reverse the word order in a string, or a pure char to char reversal like I wrote. Reversal could also mean changing character case, etc... but this is simply swap first and last. Then swap the 2nd and 2nd to last, then swap the 3rd and 3rd to last, etc...

So some points from your code. You only need to loop half the string length. The swap is from the ith  and the ith to last. So the last is numCharacters - 1, thus the ith to last would be   Last - i or numCharacters - 1 - i. I believe this is what you intended by using a farLeft(i) and a farRight(j) index.

```
#include <iostream>

void reverseStringInPlace(std::string &stringToReverse)
{
    int numCharacters = stringToReverse.length();
    for (int i=0; i<numCharacters/2; i++)
    { std::swap(stringToReverse[i], stringToReverse[numCharacters-i-1]); }
}

int main()
{
   std::string stringToReverse = "reversing a string";
   std::cout << stringToReverse << std::endl;
   reverseStringInPlace(stringToReverse);
   std::cout << stringToReverse << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

> reversing a string
>   gnirts a gnisrever

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this thread while working on the same exercise:

```
std::string s = "hello";
std::string reversed(s.size(), ' ');
for (int idx = s.length(); idx >= 0; idx--)
{
    reversed[idx] = s[idx];
}
```