# OpenGL vertices array initialisation

Tags: c, opengl, opengl-3, vertex-buffer

I have a question about OpenGL 3.0, why am I unable to draw anything when my array of vertices in initialized as

```
float * vertices;
int size = 100; // size of the vertices array
float * vertices = (float *) malloc (size*sizeof(float));
```

I have allocated memory, and initialized all the values in the array to 0.0, but it looks like my vertex buffer reads only the first element of the vertices array. Whereas when I initialize the array like this :

```
float vertices[size];
```

all the vertices are read and rendered as expected.

Here is how I specify my vertex buffer, and pass data to the buffer :

```
unsigned int VBO;
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(ourShader.ID, "aPos");

// iterpreting data from buffer 
glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3* sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

Comment: Let me guess, because you use `sizeof(vertices)`? Note `float * vertices;` `sizeof(vertices)` return the size of the pointer and not the size of the array where the pointer refers to.

Comment: You have to post more code

Comment: @Jeka I have added more code to my original question. Hope this helps clarify what I'm actually doing.

Comment: @Noob *"but it looks like my vertex buffer reads only the first element of the vertices array"* - How do you specify the *"vertex buffer"*?

Comment: I've added how I specify the vertex buffer to my question.

Comment: @Noob Pleas read my first comment!!! - Try `glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*100, vertices, GL_STREAM_DRAW);` - `sizeof(float*) != sizeof(float[100])`

Comment: @Rabbid76, I see your point now! I understand what I'm doing wrong, Thanks so much.

Comment: Possibly duplicate [What does sizeof do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203162/what-does-sizeof-do/3203180)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) doesn't do what you expect it to do. `sizeof(x)` returns the size of the data type of the variable `x`.

In case of `int size = 100;` `float vertices[size];` the data type of `vertices` is `float[100]` and `sizeof(vertices)` returns the same as `sizeof(float)*100`.

In case of `float * vertices;`, the data type of `vertices` is `float*` and `sizeof(vertices)` returns the size of the pointer data type, which points to the dynamically allocated array, but it does **not** return the size of the dynamic memory or even the number of elements of the allocated array. The size of the pointer depends on the hardware and is the same as `sizeof(void*)` (usually it is 4 or 8).

`sizeof(float) * size` would work in both of the cases of the question:

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float)*size, vertices, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
```